# Skip the deployment stage (generating root file system image)

Tags: buildroot

Is it possible to execute buildroot and have it skip the deployment stage?

In LTIB you simply add --no-deploy.

It's the most expensive step in building and 99 out of 100 times, I'm not interested in the final image because I'm using NFS to mount the target directory during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove all the BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_FOO variables from the .config

Comment: Thanks arved, I hadn't considered that. It's a bit inconvenient, but it will work. I'd like to leave the question open a bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing NFS mount, then you *have* to create at least a tarball image. Using `output/target` as your NFS mountpoint is entirely incorrect: the permissions/owernship are not correct, and device files are not present in `output/target`. Only the images generated by Buildroot have those things correct.

We even committed today a Buildroot change that strongly warns users not to use `output/target` as their root filesystem: http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/?id=9226a9907c4eb0fffab777f50e88b74aa14d1737